# Avoiding tab index on read only textBOX

Tags: c#, winforms, readonly, tabindex

Is there any method or way to avoid putting the cursor on the text box that is read only , I ordered the tools using tab index property and put the read only text box at the last but it still reachable by the user using tab key in the keyboard... Can any one explain that to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `TabStop` property value to `false`

Comment: That's perfectly what I wanted from my question thank you sir :)